# Executing VBA code makes Excel non responsive then recovers

Tags: excel, vba, freeze

This code searches to see which of the entries in Column A, do not appear in Column B.  It then writes this Column A entry, along with its adjacent Column B & Column C entries into Columns F,G,H.

After executing, it gets to iteration 350/83118 and then freezes, but recovers about 20 minutes later with the iterations complete.  As you can see, the calculation mode is set to manual, and I have tried turning off screen updating, displaying page breaks and events but it still freezes.

Any ideas to stop it freezing? I wouldn't mind it taking longer to execute the code, just as along as it doesn't freeze and reassures the user with the iteration count steadily increasing.

```
Sub MacroToCreateReducedBoMList()


Dim LR As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim Calc_Setting As Long
Dim StartTime As Double
Dim MinutesElapsed As String


StartTime = Timer
Calc_Setting = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Turning off events temporarily'
Dim EventState As Boolean
EventState = Application.EnableEvents
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Turning off page breaks temporarily'
Dim PageBreakState As Boolean
PageBreakState = ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False


Set StartCell = Range("A1")
'Find Last Row'
LastRow = StartCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

j = 2

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Range("F2:H130000").ClearContents

'MAIN CODE'
For i = 2 To LastRow
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B:B"), Range("A" & i)) = 0 Then
    Debug.Print Range("A" & i)
    Cells(j, 6) = Range("A" & i)
    Cells(j, 7) = Range("B" & i)
    Cells(j, 8) = Range("C" & i)
    j = j + 1
End If

'Message to user about current iteration'
Application.StatusBar = "Current iteration: " & i & "/" & LastRow & ".  
Please be patient, code takes roughly 20 minutes to execute, go get a coffee."

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = Calc_Setting

'Turning events back on'
Application.EnableEvents = EventState

'Turning page breaks back on'
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = PageBreakState

'Determine how many seconds code took to run
 MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

'Notify user in minutes
MsgBox "This code ran successfully in " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are doing 800k rows you probably want to be using arrays. Freezing is I think a normal response while Excel is working hard.

Comment: I don't get your code you are looping through all your rows but  j starts at 2. Are columns 6, 7, 8 always blank? Else you are losing data.

Comment: Yes, only columns A,B,C have data in.

Comment: What you actually do is to get Excel make 80k^2=6.4E9 comparisions. That takes time. You'd look for some more sophisticated solution, like loading the values to arrays, sort/index them and employ some index based search. Additionally you can still try disabling print communication. Sometimes it can help quite much. `Application.PrintCommunication = False`

Comment: @Student201 what you want to accomplish with this code is to copy the duplicates on column A vs column B?

Comment: @Damian Not the duplicates - the opposite, finding the entries of Column A which are not in column B.  And then writing this column A entry into Column F, and whatever was in the adjacent cells in Columns B and C, into Columns G and H.

Comment: There are faster ways to do that @Student201 your coworkes wouldn't have time to even go for a pee. Try storing all the data from A to H in one array, and then store in a dicitonary all the entries of column B. Finally loop through column A checking every value if exists on your dictionary. Then write it to the columns of the array and finally drop the array back to the sheet. Barely seconds would take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should put Application.ScreenUpdating = true inside the for loop and false after updating the message:

```
'Message to user about current iteration'
Application.ScreenUpdating = true
Application.StatusBar = "Current iteration: " & i & "/" & LastRow & _  
    "Please be patient, code takes roughly 20 minutes to execute, go get a coffee."
Application.ScreenUpdating = false
```

also, the worksheetFunction.CountIf probably triggers a manual recalculation of the sheet.

Answer (score 2):

If Excel takes too long running a macro, then Windows will assume that it is no longer responding, and freeze the screen.  You can mitigate this with `DoEvents`, which will let Excel to "check in" with Windows.

However, since this *does* "check in" and do events, it is also a relatively slow function - so don't call it every iteration of the loop.  The below line of code, for example, will run it with an interval of 300 rows :

```
If (i mod 300) = 0 Then DoEvents
```

You can also turn on Screen Updating, force a screen update, and then turn Screen Updating back off for a visual update.  Adding that gives you this:

```
If (i mod 300) = 0 Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.WindowState = Application.WindowState 'Force Screen Update
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    DoEvents 'Check in with Windows
End If
```